# Eclipse RCP Migration from 3 to 4: How to Replace PresenationFactory.createEditorPresentation()

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

We have a large RCP based on Eclipse 3.7 that we want to migrate to Eclipse 4. We were able to build the system successfully using the compatibility layer.

The Problem: We use our own WorkbenchPresentationFactory-Implementation that in turn uses a specialStackPresentation:

```
public class PresentationFactory extends WorkbenchPresentationFactory {

    public PresentationFactory() {}

    @Override
    public StackPresentation createEditorPresentation(Composite parent, IStackPresentationSite site) {
         return  new SimpleStackPresentation(parent, site);
    }
}
```

This SimpleStackPresentation is basically a copy of the original Eclipse 3.7 StackPresentation and accompanying "helper" classes altered so that there is always only one editor visible at a time, editors are never closed but hidden.

Now, the use of a PresentationFactory is deprecated officially in Eclipse 4, see:https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/porting/4.2/incompatibilities.php#presentationAPI

Were do I start to implement the same behavior with Eclipse 4 in conjunction with the compatibility layer?

Any help is very much appreciated!
Regards
sascha

Comment: You might be able to use a [custom renderer](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Renderer/article.html) for the stack.